# How can I check if an object is an instance of a class without including inherited classes?

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

I've looked over Google with multiple searches and searched through Stack Overflow but I can't find and answer to this simple problem. Here's some example code to show what I mean. I want to detect the class A without also detecting all class B objects

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

let x = new A();
let y = new B();

console.log(x instanceof A && y instanceof A); // Returns true because Y inherits
console.log(y isMemberOf A)); // Should return false.
```

Typeof just says "object" which isn't helpful.
What can I use to say "isMemberOf" in real JavaScript?

Comment: you want `y isMemberOf A` to return false right?

Comment: Why `y` isMemberOf `B` should be `false`?

Comment: Yes. @BadPiggie Because I'm trying to find out if the object is a member of an exact class, not including any classes it inherits

Comment: @DexieTheSheep y is an instance of B. It can't be a member of B.

Comment: Wait, I screwed up on the second console log message. Just edited the post to show what I meant.